# Can't get EF.SQLite integration to work in UWP Application

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, uwp

I have a `UWP` application targeting the Fall Creators Update. I have been following the tutorial over at [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-access/sqlite-databases) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/ef/core/get-started/uwp/getting-started).

Whenever i execute `Add-Migration`, i get an error

> Startup project 'UEX.Apps.Enforce.UWP' is a Universal Windows Platform app. This version of the Entity Framework Core Package Manager Console Tools doesn't support this type of project. For more information on using the EF Core Tools with UWP projects, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=858496

I am at a loss here. This seems to not work at all.

What have i tried: Setting up a fresh Windows 10 VM with Fall Creators Update. Installing a fresh copy of VS2017. Copy the project to the new machine. Still gives me the same error.

I find it difficult to isolate the code as it is just basic entity framwork initialization code. I think the error lies somewhere in the meta info. As i have tried with a fresh VS2017 installation, i don't think its about messed up packages or anything.

I have reduced my project to just the project files and the context plus one entity. I have uploaded it here:

> https://1drv.ms/u/s!AqqIr8PxNnQDjMU92f5cWkhQpeD-GQ

**EDIT**: based on Nico Zhus answer, i have followed [the tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/ef/core/get-started/uwp/getting-started#create-your-model) step by step and put my model class into a separate `.net Standard class library`. I edited the project file and added the EF references. However, there is a step missing in this tutorial, that details how you can actually reference your model code from your `UWP` project, as adding the actual reference is not mentioned. I try to add the reference via the right-click `Add reference` menu, selected the `.net standard class library`, but got an error.

> Unable to add reference to project <...>

I also set the class library as my startup project, executed the `Add-Migration` command, and it does not throw any exceptions, but it also doesn't add the migration files i was expecting. Nothing happens.

**EDIT 2**:

As per I changed the Nico Zhus comment, i changed the `TargetFramework` property of project file of the `.net standard class library` back to what it originally was and now i can reference the `class library` from my `UWP` project. However, i still cannot execute `Add-Migration` on my Model project

> Startup project 'my project' targets framework '.NETStandard'. There is no runtime associated with this framework, and projects targeting it cannot be executed directly. To use the Entity Framework Core Package Manager Console Tools with this project, add an executable project targeting .NET Framework or .NET Core that references this project, and set it as the startup project; or, update this project to cross-target .NET Framework or .NET Core.

Comment: Why dont you use EntityWorker.Core is much easer. https://github.com/AlenToma/EntityWorker.Core

Comment: Have you modified the **Min version** of project to Windows 10 Fall Creators Update(10.0;Build 16299)?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Yes, i have set both versions to Fall Creators update. I also wanted to add the TargetFrameworks tag to my project file, but that didnt work either (this added 2 new dependencies that had the yellow warning symbol on it. project didnt build after, so i changed my project file back) Can i provide anything else that would help in finding the issue?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I will try but this seems more like a general error in how this determined? A configuration error in one of the meta files maybe? I mean, i have just created new UWP app, added the packages, created a dbcontext with some entities and called add-migration. However i am setting up a fresh VM right now and will install everything from start and will try to reproduce this. I mean, until then, i guess i could share the contents of the project file? Would that help?

Comment: Yep, because I could not reproduce your issue in my side, So I want more detail or your  simple sample to reproduce it.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT please see my updated question for a onedrive link. I hope this works for you, as i could not pin down this problem to some code lines.

Comment: I have check your sample, the problem is `Add-Migration` only available in Class Library (.NET Standard).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Startup project 'UEX.Apps.Enforce.UWP' is a Universal Windows Platform app. This version of the Entity Framework Core Package Manager Console Tools doesn't support this type of project. For more information on using the EF Core Tools with UWP projects, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=858496

According to [Getting Started with EF Core on Universal Windows Platform (UWP) with a New Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/ef/core/get-started/uwp/getting-started), you need to create a new model project(**Class Library (.NET Standard)**) for your UWP app. And before you execute tool command(`Add-Migration MyFirstMigration`), you need to select the **model project** as the Default project and set it as the startup project in the soution. 
[image]

**Update**

Before you executed tool command, you need to  put the following in the csproj file of the `Model` project:

```
<PropertyGroup>
 <GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>true</GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>
</PropertyGroup>
```

If you have added migration files successfully, you could change `TargetFramework` back to make sure it could be referenced by UWP project.

```
<TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0</TargetFrameworks>
```

Comment: I will give this a try, however the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-access/sqlite-databases) states "Lets start by adding a .NET Standard 2.0 class library to your solution. It's not necessary that you use a class library to contain your data access code, but we'll use one our example." I see that it is required from the link you posted, so the wording could be corrected to avoid misunderstandings like this

Comment: When i try to add a reference to the project i get the error message that i can't add the .net standard class library project.

Comment: Please edit the model project .csproj file and replace `<TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp2.0;netstandard2.0</TargetFrameworks>`with `<TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>` .

Comment: I did this, and then executed Add-Migration, but got this: "Startup project 'UEX.MinSamp.Model' targets framework '.NETStandard'. There is no runtime associated with this framework, and projects targeting it cannot be executed directly. To use the Entity Framework Core Package Manager Console Tools with this project, add an executable project targeting .NET Framework or .NET Core that references this project, and set it as the startup project; or, update this project to cross-target .NET Framework or .NET Core.".

Comment: Yep, I have reproduced your issue(**doesn't add the migration files**), I will check the package manager console.

Comment: I'm having the same issues. It seems that a number of cases have popped up online, and they all are from this year (2018). Something appears to be broken.

Comment: have a look at https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityWorker.Core/ it much easer to work with